# Tkinter - How to disable button when window opened

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm new to the **'Tkinter' library** and I wanted to know how to disable a button when a new window has been opened. For example, if a button on the main window is clicked, a new window will open, and all buttons on the main window will be disabled. After the window is closed, the buttons should be re-enabled again.

Here's a sample of my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def z():
    w = Toplevel()

    bu = Button(w, text = "Click!", font = 'bold')
    bu.pack()

b = Button(root, text = "Click!", command = z)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**Extra:** I would also be grateful if someone could tell me how to close the 'root' window without closing the whole 'Tkinter' program. For example, if a secondary window is open, I would like to be able to close the first window, or at least minimize it.

Comment: root is main window and it always closes other sub windows. If you want to close `root` then after that create new `root` window `Tk()` with new `mainloop()`

Comment: `b['state'] = 'disabled'`  and `b['state'] = 'normal'`

Comment: `root.iconify()` or `root.withdraw()` and `root.deiconify()`

Answer (score 1):

You can hide window

```
root.withdraw()

# or 

root.iconify()
```

and show again

```
root.deiconify()
```

---

To disable button

```
b['state'] = 'disabled'
```

To enable button

```
b['state'] = 'normal'
```

---

**EDIT:** as @acw1668 noted in comment it needs `win.protocol()` to run `close_second` when user used closing button [X] on title bar

```
import tkinter as tk # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

#--- functions ---

def close_second():
    win.destroy()

    b['state'] = 'normal'

    root.deiconify()

def open_second():
    global win

    b['state'] = 'disabled'
    #root.iconify()
    root.withdraw()

    win = tk.Toplevel()

    win_b = tk.Button(win, text="Close Second", command=close_second)
    win_b.pack()

    # run `close_second` when user used closing button [X] on title bar
    win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", close_second)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

b = tk.Button(root, text="Open Second", command=open_second)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The root window may not be deiconified if the toplevel is closed by clicking the close button on the title bar.

Comment: @acw1668 good point, I aways forgot it. I added `win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", close_second)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use .grab_set() to disable interacting with the main window. You can close the window when the button is clicked and reopen the last window when the other button is clicked one is closed like so:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def reopen():
    root.mainloop()
    w.withdraw()

def z():
    w = Toplevel()
    w.grab_set()
    bu = Button(w, text = "Click!", font = 'bold', command=reopen)
    bu.pack()
    root.withdraw()
    w.mainloop()

b = Button(root, text = "Click!", command = z)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -3):

Welcome to Tkinter Library.

I done why you are using that 'w' you can just use root and it work.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def z():

    bu = Button(root, text = "Click!", font = 'bold')
    bu.pack()

b = Button(root, text = "Click!", command = z)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Ask me if you get any problem in python and tkinter